# How the find the distance between a given point and a line?

Tags: geometry

I would like some help with geometry. I need to find the answer to the following questions

Line L: $y = x + 1$

Point P: = $(-5, -3)$

a: Determine the line that is perpendicular to line L and crosses point P.

b: Calculate the distance between line L and point P. Give your answer with $2$ decimals.

How would one go about calculating this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line perpendicular to L will have a slope of -1 .Therefore  use the general formula of a straight line as $y=mx+c$ .Here $m=1$ calculate c by putting the coordinates of point p . 
Next, the distance between a point and a line $(ax+by+c=0)$ is $|(ah+bk+c)|/(√(a^2+b^2)$)

Comment: @NovemberDeveloper the answer should be $y+x+8=0 $ and $1/√2$ ie $0.7071$

Comment: Thank you so much!